# Keeping Texture Mode Appearance While Exporting to Unity

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, export, unity

I am attempting to export my Blender model to Unity but I'm having trouble retaining the view while in texture mode. The issue is that I actually haven't added a texture layer to the model (at least that I can tell), but it still looks much different when I switch modes.

Does anyone have any ideas on why my model would look different in texture mode (as opposed to solid or material mode) and what I could do to retain that appearance when exporting to Unity?

I've attached some screenshots to see the differences below:

Solid mode:

[image: Solid Mode]

Material mode:

[image: Material Mode]

Texture mode:

[image: Texture mode]

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem with your model. If you change material color (diffuse+specular), in the Texture mode you will see those colors displayed, a little bit different than in Material node. If you haven't assigned any material or didn't change its settings, it will display white color, which is what by default. This is as it should be

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is there any way to get that texture appearance to stick in Unity? I'm able to reapply the material but it only makes it look like the material mode screenshot as opposed to the texture mode screenshot.

Comment: Could you please upload the example of your .blend file on something like [pasteall.org](http://pasteall.org/blend) ? I'd say you could add a texture to your model and simply fill it with that color you'd like. Still I'm not sure which options have you changed in material so it may not work

Comment: Ok here's the link to the .blend file. Thanks for your help: http://pasteall.org/blend/37440

Comment: Did I understand you right that you'd like to make parts of model with material "red full.001" while rendered look exactly as do those bright red arms in Texture mode ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your model while rendered have that bright red color you see in Texture shading 3D view mode you can setup it in 2 ways:

1. Make the material shadeless:

   [image]

   The result:

   [image]

   However, it's not good approach as it's much less flexible; you will loose possibility of the material to have shadows and thus it may not suit your needs.
2. You can setup a texture for your material.

   With that material selected (`"red full.001"` in your case) go to *Texture* tab and create new one. Select it's type **Blend** and check **Ramp** option in  *Colors* scroll. Delete one of the color stops, select another and copy the color from your material setup to this color stop (it may be easier to use *Hex triplet* for that):

   [image]
   *Note: the texture should be checked to influence on the material (near its name in the list); I forgot to check it back when I made screenshots*

   The resulting material is bright, at the same time receiving shadows:

   [image]

   I also checked **Color** checkbox in *Specular* options in the *Influence* scroll (so the texture to influence on the specularity, instead of material; to return material specularity color uncheck that).

Comment: Thanks so much, this seems to be just what I'm looking for. So far it seems to be working--I'm going to attempt to export my file into Unity and see if the texture is retained.

Answer (score 0):

Solid mode displays only the viewport color you have set in the materials tab unlike the material mode and texture mode, material mode is showing the light highlights unlike Solid mode and Texture mode.
When you will import your model to unity you will not see any textures as you have to manually apply them to your materials, just drag you textures to the albedo of the material or just drag the texture on to the object.

Comment: The main issue I have is that I don't seem to have applied any textures at all to my model (only materials) and yet it looks completely different while in texture mode. Do you know why this might be the case?